# VPS - Disk space usage shown in explorer higher than reported by WinDirStat, ideas?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vps

I have a VPS with Windows 2003. At the moment in explorer for a 50GB hard drive shows that there is only about 2GB free, I ran WinDirStat and it shows that files are using 14GB.
this is a VPS that runs on top of virtuozzo.

Any ideas why?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have volume shadow copy service (VSS) enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that there loads of log files in c:\windows\system32\Logfiles

i m talking about 33+ GB and windirstat did not see them.

I ran windirstat with a higher permission set and it did find 33GB of pdb files but it couldnt tell me where they were or any other info, and it only showed me that when i put view Unknown. so a bit disappointed that windirstat could not see these log files

I thought I should post this in case there is someone else with this prob

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Since I still couldn’t see the filepath for the “Unknown” files, it was pretty useless. This dilemma led me on a quest for a windirstat alternative that properly showed system32 files. WizTree seems to be the golden alternative: fast and showed windirstat’s problem files perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Possibly file/disk compression on the server file system or on the VM host virtual storage container/file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
[How to restore missing space in NTFS file systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/9144/how-to-restore-missing-space-in-ntfs-file-systems)

Particularly the bit that says:

> I'd also look at system restore. Try
>   running WinDirStat as SYSTEM using
>   PsExec and see if there is a large
>   amount of files under System Volume
>   Information named Restore{GUID}.